# Bootstrap navbar toggle button not working correctly (HTML inside)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, toggle

When i open my site on lower resolutions (<768px) the menu button (3 bars) shows up, but when i click it it doesnt show the collapsed navbar.
What am i doing wrong? I think ive linked everything correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Lol-Smurfs.com | Squidat</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="estilo1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900,700,600italic,600,200,200italic,300,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <center>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Why us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: thats not the complete code, just showing the header, but added the last lines of the code where im linking js

Comment: Your code works in jsfiddle. Link here: https://jsfiddle.net/j7j6h063/

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors and why are you using multiple Bootstrap stylesheets?

Comment: What the hell, as Jay said it works in jfiddle but it doesnt work when i open my site on firefox

Comment: You can check it here, where it doesnt work http://squidbussiness.xyz/ Vanburen- My bad, already deleted one of the bootstrap css links

Comment: Is the `bootstrap.min.js` definitely in the location it says?

Comment: If you open up the Console in DevTools you'll see you're receiving a **404 error (Not Found)** for your bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the bad bootstrap.js link, fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your code with this.

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
       <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was referring to the bootstrap.js in an invalid location

```html
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the fix:

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```